# How to fix "EOF when reading a line" using plugin Python-Notepad++

Tags: python-2.7, notepad++, user-input

I'm using python plugin in Notepad++ and trying to use `input()` in a script I get this error

```
>>> name=input()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

I've tried solutions in other threads of SO like using try/except block as below, but still getting the error. Is there a workaround for this? Thank you.

```
>>> try:
...     input("Please enter something")
... except:
...     break
File "<console>", line 4
SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop


>>> try:
...     name=input()
... except EOFError:
...     break
File "<console>", line 4
SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

**UPDATE**

```
>>> try:
...     input("Please enter something: ")
... except EOFError as e:
...     print(e)
... 
Please enter something: EOF when reading a line
>>> abc
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'abc' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

change `break` to `pass` and you should pass that error or use

```
except EOFError as e:
    print(e)
```

so you will know when it happened. All I can help as I can't replicate it here, works just fine for me. Use `break` only in loops.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried as you mentioned (please see code below `UPDATE` in original post). With your suggestion now is mixed, it asks to enter the text but after that shows the error again.

Comment: add variable name to your input. Not input() but eg. word = input(), You will get error as in the description, there is no variable abc and you are only have exception for eof.

Comment: Adding variable is exactly the same. It seems there is no solution for this. Notepad++ python plugin runs python 2.7. I've tried with raw_input() and the same issue.

Comment: did you try to actually input something or did you just pressed enter? In your update, apart of not having input assign to variable everything looks as it should.

Comment: One more thing, you've tagged question as python 3.x but said plugin runs 2.7???

Comment: I changed to python 2.7. And yes, I've tried to enter something and the error still happens. I found a way to get input from user with `notepad.prompt()` since python input() doesn't work. Thanks for your help and time